# React / Partially sticky footer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on a nextjs project with Material UI. I am to create a page with an app bar, essentially unlimited contents in the middle, and a footer.

I am trying to create a partially sticky footer, where the Top part is just a small orange bar, which is already implemented using css

```
export default function Footer() { 
    return ( <div style={{ position: "fixed", width: "100%", backgroundColor: Colors.orange6, bottom: "0", left: "0", height: 16, }} /> );
}
```

I need to create a bottom part of the footer, which is partially sticky. It will only be visible when scrolled to the bottom.

What would be an elegant way to implement this?

Comment: Hi,  welcome to SO! I suggest you giving it a try yourself and then asking about any problems you encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking if you are at the bottom of the page and conditionally hide and show your footer.

```
const App = () => {
  const [isBottom, setIsBottom] = React.useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => {

    const bottom = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight

    if (bottom) {
      setIsBottom(true)
    } else {
      setIsBottom(false)
    }

  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, {
      passive: true
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
     <div>content.....</div>
    <footer className={isBottom ? "showFooter" : "hideFooter"}>M</footer>
    )
};
```